# How to find electric field inside a non-uniformly charged cylindrical shell?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

We are given an infinitely long  thin cylindrical shell. The axis of this cylinder coincides with the z-axis. 
The cylinder carries a surface charge, with surface charge density given by $\sigma=\sigma_0 \space cos\phi$, where $\phi$ is the polar angle and $\sigma_0$ is a constant.
The question is - what is the magnitude of the electric field inside the cylinder?

My understanding---

[image]

Inside the cylindrical shell there exists no charge at all. Now to calculate the field at any point inside the cylinder we draw a small cylindrical gaussian surface, then from Gauss's law,
\begin{equation}
\oint_s\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}=\frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0},
\end{equation}
we see that since $Q_{enclosed}=0$, thus $E=0.$

But I am also thinking, since the surface charge density is non-uniform, so how can the net field inside cancel out?

Note: Possibly answer to my question, i.e. field inside the cylindrical shell is non-zero.
But I cannot understand how!?

Comment: It is true that since $Q_{enclosed}$ is $0$. However, this only implies that the total electric flux is zero, not the electric field itself is zero. The latter happens only in special cases. You can verify this by solving the Poisson equation for the electric potential with appropriate boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The implication "$\oint_S d\vec S \cdot \vec E = 0 \Rightarrow E = 0$" is wrong. This is easy to see – just choose a prism within a homogenous electric field with the bases perpendicular to $\vec E$, then the flux through the sides will be zero and the flux through the bases will have equal magnitude but opposite sign. So the flux will through the prism surface will be zero (which is expected, after all there are no charges in the box, so we expect this from Gauß's law) – but $E \ne 0$.
2. Your problem does not have sufficient symmetry to be solved by the typical Gauß-law based tricks. They only work if, by symmetry, you can derive surfaces where all parts are either perpendicular or parallel $\vec E$, and $\vec E$ is constant on those parts of the surface, that are perpendicular to $\vec E$.
3. I think, you can derive the field along the axis of the cylinder by a Gauß argument.